# Perl regexp with utf8 chars

Tags: perl

I have these two files: `t.pl` and `t`:

```
$ file t.pl t
t.pl: UTF-8 Unicode text
t:    UTF-8 Unicode text
$ cat t
日本
```

t.pl has three versions:

**case 1**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

$_='日本';
if(/日/){
    print "match!\n";
 }
```

and `perl t.pl` outpus `match!`

**case 2**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    if(/日/){
        print "match!\n";
    }
}
__DATA__
日本
```

also `match!`

then **case 3**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

while(<>){
    chomp;
    if(/日/){
        print "match!\n";
    }
}
```

`perl t.pl t` does not show `match!`

So what's wrong with case 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the encoding for the input, `use utf8` does not do that for you. Just insert

```
use open IN => ":utf8";
```

before the loop. See [open](https://metacpan.org/module/open) for details.

Comment: Probably want the more general `use open ':std', ':utf8';`